# Как правильно: проведены соревнования или проведено соревнование по волейболу?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Проведены соревнования по волейболу.
Проведено соревнование по волейболу

Comment: А что было на самом деле - несколько матчей или один?

Answer (score 1):

Толковые словари приводят примеры со значением в единственном числе только для "соревнование в", а "соревнования по" — во множественном.

Словарь Ожегова:

> СОРЕВНОВАНИЕ — СОРЕВНОВАНИЕ, я, ср. Форма деятельности (работы, игры), при которой участвующие стремятся превзойти друг друга. Вступить в с. Спортивные соревнования. С. в стрельбе. Соревнования по фигурному катанию.

Словарь Кузнецова:

> СОРЕВНОВАНИЕ,-я; ...
>   2. обычно мн.: соревнования, -ний. Спортивная встреча для установления первенства по какому-л. виду спорта; состязание. Соревнования по плаванию. Соревнования по стрельбе. Соревнования по фигурному катанию. С. в беге.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **Проведены соревнования по волейболу.**

1) **Соревнование  (ед.ч.)** ― это название действия, выраженного глаголом ***соревноваться*** (в чем). Это название темы, но  обычно  этом случае **используется именно глагол с предлогом В, а не существительное:**

Спортсмены будут **соревноваться в** мужском и женском одиночном катании, парном фигурном катании и в спортивных танцах на льду. Сначала с**остязались в стрельбе** из лука и арбалета,

2) **Соревнования по  (мн.ч.)** ― это **спортивная встреча**. Были проведены **соревнования по фигурному катанию**. Проходят всероссийские соревнования **по стрельбе из лука.**

Из словаря:

СОРЕВНОВАТЬСЯ,  Стремиться добиться лучших результатов по сравнению с кем-л., превзойти кого-л. в каком-л. отношении. С. в учёбе.  С. в беге на коньках.

СОРЕВНОВАНИЕ, 1. к Соревноваться. Вступить в с.  2. **обычно мн.: соревнования**, **Спортивная встреча** для установления первенства по какому-л. виду спорта;  С. по плаванию. С. по фигурному катанию. С. в беге.

Comment: В последнем примере сокращение "С." означает не **соревнования**, а **соревнование** (сокращение названия основной словарной статьи). В других словарных статьях этого словаря примеры написаны полностью: "соревнование по многоборью", "соревнование по пушболу" и т.п. Меня удивляет, что в этой редакции словаря убраны примеры во множественном числе (см. для сравнения цитату в моём ответе из этого словаря 2000 г. издания).

Comment: Если не углубляться в словари: Я смотрела в поисковике, но не нашла там "соревнование в стрельбе", но только "соревноваться в стрельбе" или соревнования по стрельбе. Мне кажется, что по частотности употребления это именно так. Предлог В определяет ВИД СПОРТА (соревноваться в стрельбе) , а предлог ПО обозначает соответствие, направленность проводимой СПОРТИВНОЙ ВСТРЕЧИ.

Comment: Просьба не воспринимать мой комментарий как возражение, я только хотел отметить любопытное изменение в словаре (ведь такое изменение не могло быть сделано по ошибке). А с Вашим ответом я согласен.